# I need a mix between FileDialog and DirectoryDialog

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

If I use the DirectoryDialog , only I can choose one directory.  If I use FileDialog, I can choose multiple files.
I am looking for a SWT/JFace dialog, who be a mix .

I have found, JFileChooser but is not a SWT component. 
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes, JFileChooser is a Swing class, located in the JDK. See this [excellent article by Vogella on how to work with dialogs in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html)